# How to send mesage to rabitmq according spring boot getting started

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am trying follow steps from  [GETTING STARTED
Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#initial)

I have downloaded and started rabitmq.
I use windows and it lauched as service:

[image]

I downloaded project skeleton and typed code from the article.
Thus project structure looks like this:

[image]

**Application:**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    final static String queueName = "spring-boot";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

**Runner:**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
                  ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Then in the guide written that I need to start main method and I will see output like this:

> Sending message...
>   Received

But I don't see these lines.
I see only lines like:

```
15:51:45.720 [container-1] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer@5bb8f9e2: tags=[{amq.ctag-2wLW2IpZdDrHrPqtlqOd4Q=spring-boot}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@3921095e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@226c7c81 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53157], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:51:46.721 [container-1] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer@5bb8f9e2: tags=[{amq.ctag-2wLW2IpZdDrHrPqtlqOd4Q=spring-boot}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@3921095e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@226c7c81 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53157], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:51:47.722 [container-1] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer@5bb8f9e2: tags=[{amq.ctag-2wLW2IpZdDrHrPqtlqOd4Q=spring-boot}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@3921095e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@226c7c81 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53157], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

### P.S.

I understand That `Runner` class is not using in my application but I don't understand how to instantiate it and where to invoke. I can't find relevant information in guide.

Please, help me start my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
}
```

We talk here about Spring Boot, therefore that code must be:

```
SpringAplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-main-method

Comment: what the class SpringAplication ? what the package?

Comment: `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication`. A good IDE should suggest you proper package to import.

Comment: Me too, already more than 10 year and I'm happy with it. so, not sure what's wrong with auto imports in your case...

Comment: I became too lazy to hit alt+enter

Comment: Can you clarify how does Runner class instantiates?  This one has Receiver and RabbitTemplate dependencies but I don't see @Autowired annotation. I missed something or now spring try to autowire all fields by default?

Comment: ??? You have there ctor and, yes, right now ctor injections are performed by default

Comment: I don't know. Looks like for a while already: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.3.html    since 4.3

Comment: some additional things I don't understand. 1. What the reason to await after sending message from running ? . run method will hangs after convertAndSend because of latch. It will go forward inly after receiving mesage. But why? Why can't we just close contexte inside receiver?

Comment: That's true. But if you are interested to see the `receive` in work you have to wait for the `latch`, just because the `receive` happens in the the separate thread from the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: I agree that if we want to invoker **context.close()** inside Runner - we need to await when message will be received. But why we couldn't invoke this line just inside  **Receiver#receiveMessage** ?

Comment: What line? `context.close()`? Well, that's already up to you. But from the design perspective that's not correct place to do that. In real app your receiver will consume messages from the RabbitMQ constantly. You're indeed not going to stop your app just after the first message.

Comment: I think this is already too long chat with non-related subjects to the original issue